# Cloudflare Error 525 (if trying to connect via https ports) websocket

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, socket.io, cloudflare

I'm currently trying to test a websocket based php chat.
https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket

This is what I'm currently trying just to **test**.
But I'm using cloudflare & normally it should work fine using cloudflare but I always get

```
Error 525
SSL handshake failed
```

when I try to visit it like that:
https://example.com:2096/chat/server.php

& same result if I try to use the chat ofc. but that's for every domain using https ports, 8443 same result etc.

I'm using "Full (strict)" mode & I have a signed certificate installed by cloudflare installed, so I don't really know where the problem is, using wss & it worked when I disabled SSL, but I want to make it work over SSL ofc.

visiting my website without using https ports works fine, so it can't be the "strict" mode, tested normal "full" & flexible but same result.

Thanks for any help in advance.

edit--

[config (site infinite loading)](https://pastebin.com/fTQ2E92W)

[error log file](https://pastebin.com/pwHKg8Am)

Comment: Are using apache2 or nginx. Also can you show us your config file?

Comment: I'm using apache2 (xampp). I don't know how I could show you my config file without an external link but here: [link](https://pastebin.com/D6Dv0DvP) that's the httpd-ssl.conf file (a part of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that you're probably missing the `SSLProxyCACertificateFile` directive.

I am grabbing this config straight from our production server using Socket.io with Nodejs. I think this might help.

```sh
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName exmample.com
        ServerAlias www.exmample.com
        ServerAdmin admin@exmample.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exmample.com

        LogLevel debug  ssl:info
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key

        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 1
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ca/origin-pull-ca.pem

        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ca/origin-pull-ca.pem


        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule .* "wss:/localhost:2096/$1" [P,L]
  
        #Redirecting websocket traffic
        ProxyPass /shut / wss://localhost:2096/shut
        ProxyPassReverse /shut wss://localhost:2096/shut

        #Redirecting http traffic
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:2096/shut
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2096/shut
   


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/exmaple_error_https.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_access_https.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222211/discussion-on-answer-by-aviv-lo-cloudflare-error-525-if-trying-to-connect-via-h).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding that in my httpd-ssl.conf

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\ssl\origin-pull-ca.pem"

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCACertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\ssl\origin-pull-ca.pem"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond ${HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule .* "ws://localhost:8443/$1" [P,L]
  
#Redirecting websocket traffic
ProxyPass /server ws://localhost:8443/server
ProxyPassReverse /server ws://localhost:8443/server
```

Thanks to Aviv Lo for wasting his time on helping me for more than a hour! Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't say that @opalutscha. It was a very nice experience solving the problem together. I appreciated it a lot as well :)